# Conflicting CSS Overflow Property - How to Fix?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a Nice CSS3 menu that works great however I am also incorporating a [1140px Grid System](http://cssgrid.net/). The 1140px system has a class that looks like so:

```
.row {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1140px;
 min-width: 755px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

The `overflow: hidden;` is preventing the menu drop down on the menu from working correctly. Here is the HTML of the menu:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="twelvecol logo">
<h1><a href="/">Logo</a></h1>

   <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">2012</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">January</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">February</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">March</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">April</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">May</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">June</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">July</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">August</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">September</a></li>

             <li><a href="#">October</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  <!-- MORE CODE -->
```

I have attempted to override the overflow property by adding `overflow: visible !important;` but that breaks the page completely.

Can anyone help with a solution that will resolve the issue and show the menu properly *without* having to remove the 1140px Grid System?

Here is a [jsFiddle I created](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/Saajh/1/).

Note: I do not mind using a solution that uses jQuery if that is what works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following to the CSS solves the problem

```
#navigation ul
{
    position: absolute;
left: 500px;
min-width: 300px;
}
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Saajh/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
#navigation ul{
  position:absolute;
 right:0;
}
#navigation li ul{
 width:110px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a new class at your container:

```
<div class="row notoverflow">
```

in your css:

```
.row.notoverflow{overflow:auto}
```

and at the end of your container

```
<div class="row notoverflow">. . .
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Without the `overflow:hidden` property, the container height wouldn't increase with his content ... The other way to do that is to clear the floats.

Comment: That does not work. That causes scroll bars to appear when the menu is hovered over.

Comment: I gave you an alternative way to the overflow:hidden in your .row ... The problem is in your menu ... he's pushing the content, you must give it a `position:absolute`

Answer (score 0):

You could also remove the entire Nav div from within the containing div so that it comes first in the document flow....as in above